# App ID and Token for facebook API needs to be reviewed and need some advice

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can someone please give advice what to do for 2 small facebook plugins made in php

I sell 2 small sripts on codecanyon (1 for wordpress) https://codecanyon.net/item/social-facebook-posts-timeline-php-class/11855149

What it does is fetching posts from a business facebook acount.
Till april every buyer mades his own APP id and Token and could fetch the posts.

Now every app has to be reviewed and for the buyers this is to difficult and they don't understand anything of this procedure.

Three things I can do, stop selling, let users use an pagetoken (but that expires every six months and inconvience for the buyers) or can I make one APP for my self and put that app id and token into my plugins (will I reach the limit then easy?)

I hope you guys have some advice for me

Thx for reading [image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Extended Page Tokens expire after 2 months. The best way imho is to go through the review process with your App, and let people use your App to generate a Page Token for their Page. No problems with rate limits then, because each user uses his own Token. That way, users do not even need to create any App.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension says extended page tokens are valid for up to 60 days now